# Route model binding, Provider, Middleware, constructor or function specific

Tags: laravel

In most projects, you often have a route where you have multiple params

```
/posts/1/comments/1
```

And you want to make sure that comment 1 is part of posts 1.

You can do these multiple ways.

**Abort_if() or Abort_unless()**

Like this

```
abort_if($post->id != $comment->post_id, 403);
```

or

```
abort_unless($post->id == $comment->post_id, 403);
```

The con is that this needs to be at every controller function that interacts with both comment and post. A lot of repeating code. Not really that DRY

**Middleware**

You could make a middleware that does this check, and place it on the desired route.

The con with this one, you'll need to place this at every route you need this, the same thing like the abort option.

**Route model binding**

This looks like the best option, a global way of querying from the posts model.

```
$posts->comments()->where($comment->id);
```

The con here, if you bind 'comment' to be always searched in the relation of posts then you will never be able to do

```
/comments/1
```

What are your thoughts? Can't really seem to find a best practice nor a definitive answer.